# Customizing JWT token claims in Django

Tags: python, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm trying to customize my JWT token and what ever I do I got an error like this :

`ImportError: cannot import name 'MyTokenObtainPairView' from 'base.api.serializers' (D:\Anaraki\api\bakend\base\api\serializers.py)`

here is my `serializers.py` file:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        # Add custom claims
        token['username'] = user.username

        return token
    
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path    
from . import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (TokenRefreshView, TokenObtainPairView)
from .serializers import MyTokenObtainPairView

# to customize the token we use this one insted .
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.getRoutes),
    path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

I did everything's that doc said but I still got this ... error, please help me.

Comment: I still don't know why, but I run this code on another laptop, and it's working there !!!